# How to ignore a member of a struct-like enum variant in pattern matching?

Tags: enums, rust

How do I remove the `unused_variables` warning from the following code?

```
pub enum Foo {
    Bar {
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
        c: i32,
    },
    Baz,
}

fn main() {
    let myfoo = Foo::Bar { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    let x: i32 = match myfoo {
        Foo::Bar { a, b, c } => b * b,
        Foo::Baz => -1,
    };
    assert_eq!(x, 4);
}
```

I know I can ignore struct members after a certain point with:

```
Foo::Bar { a, .. } => // do stuff with 'a'
```

But I can't find documentation anywhere that explains how to ignore individual struct members.

[Code on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7016ceb97f3c088fba1be57a73ff3fee&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Incidentally, there's no need for `let x: i32 =` - that type will be inferred and you can just say `let x =`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I know I can ignore struct members after a certain point with:

The `..` is not positional. It just means "all the other fields":

```
Foo::Bar { b, .. } => b * b,
```